# instamojo payment gate way implementation in server

Tags: php

we are using instamojo  payment gate way in our website,its working successfully in localhost but not in live server(godady) its getting error like 500(page not working). may i request you can you suggest me to solve my problem 
 we are using below code

```
<?php 
$product_name=$_POST['product_name'];
$price=$_POST['product_price'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
include 'src/instamojo.php';
$api = new Instamojo\Instamojo('a9979a24478f77cf21688ca8a8f46151', '025caf249cec5ad8345192a15e71602b');


try {
    $response = $api->paymentRequestCreate(array(
        "purpose" => $product_name,
        "amount" => $price,
        "buyer_name" => $name,
        "phone" => $phone,
        "send_email" => true,
        "send_sms" => false,
        "email" => $email,
        "allow_repeated_payments" => false,
        "redirect_url" => "http://e2dshop.com/thanq.php",
        "webhook" => "http://e2dshop.com/webhook.php"


        ));
   // print_r($response);
    $pay_ulr = $response['longurl'];
  echo "<script>window.location.href='$pay_ulr'</script>";
   //header("Location : $pay_ulr");
   exit();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    print('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been very long since you asked your question, but today i faced the same issue so I am sharing my solution.

The code you pasted will work fine on localhost, but will show HTTP Error 500.
For the payment gateway to work on GoDaddy or on any live server you need to use CURL.
Please refer to the code below.

```
    <?php
    if((isset($_POST['totalAmount'])) && (!empty($_POST['totalAmount'])))
    {
    $amount = $_POST['totalAmount'];
    $purpose = $_POST['product_name'];
    $phone = $_POST['buyer_phone'];
    $buyername = $_POST['buyer_name'];
    $email = $_POST['buyer_email'];

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.instamojo.com/api/1.1/payment-requests/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
     array("X-Api-Key:yourApiKeyHere",
     "X-Auth-Token:yourAuthTokenHere"));
    $payload = Array(
     'purpose' => $purpose,
     'amount' => $amount,
     'phone' => $phone,
     'buyer_name' => $buyername,
     'redirect_url' => 'https://www.yourwebsitehere.com/thankyou.php',
     'webhook' => 'https://www.yourwebsitehere.com/webhook.php',
     'send_email' => true,
     'send_sms' => true,
     'email' => $email,
     'allow_repeated_payments' => false
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($payload));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 


    $data = json_decode($response,true);
    var_dump($data);
    $site=$data["payment_request"]["longurl"];
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location:'.$site); 

    } else {
     header("Location:payment.php");
    }

    ?>
```

I hope this helps you or the others who's facing the same issue currently :)
Give's a thumbs up if this helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved my problem..  Can you please share code for "thankyou.php" & "webhoo.php" ?